# How do I fix or finish a partially sanded wood floor

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing, wood-finishing

In my home office (it was a bedroom before and will be one in the future) I have a wooden floor (not laminate) and I have an office chair with plastic wheels on it. Over a number of years these plastic wheels have "sanded" the varnish/finish off the wood and I'm now at the point that I want to repair this.

Is it possible for me to paint something over this section of floor to make it look like (or almost like) the rest of the floor. If so, what would that something be?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "wipe on" polyurethane might get you most of the way there, depending upon how perfect you want to get it.   Lightly sand the damaged area to make sure there are no sharp edges or rough spots. Then with a lint free cloth, wipe on some (it'll take a few coats) and see if you like it.   If good enough, great, if not, and you really want it right, you'll have to sand the entire floor to bare wood and re-finish it all.

[image: Wipe on Polyurethane]

Answer (score 0):

something would be polyurethane floor varnish